# How to get block comments in user defined language to work properly in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I am building a definition for a propriatery language that uses c style comment blocks.

I have set the following:

Comment open: /* 
Comment close: */ 
Treat keywords as symbols (in Comment Block frame): Checked

I do not have `*` or `/` set as activated operators.

This results in the following formatting: 
(I've commented the comments to show if the comments were treated as comments by the commenting engine of notepad++)

```
/*comment*/   //comment
code          //comment (but should be code)
/* comment */ //comment
code          //code
/**/code/**/  //comment (but should be code)
code          //comment (but should be code)
/*comment     //comment
comment       //comment
comment*/     //comment
code          //code
/*            //comment
comment       //comment
*/            //comment
```

If I uncheck Treat keywords as symbols I get this:

```
/*comment*/   //code (but should be comment)
code          //code
/* comment */ //comment
code          //code
/**/code/**/  //code (both /**/ show as code as well)
code          //code
/*comment     //code (but should be comment)
comment       //code (but should be comment)
comment*/     //code (but should be comment)
code          //code
/*            //comment
comment       //comment
*/            //comment
```

I have also tried every commbination of Treat keywords as symbols and adding `*` and `/` to the operator list.